RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop error while creating telegram bot
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncTeleBot.polling' was never awaited
import asyncio
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot

bot = AsyncTeleBot(TOKEN)

.....


asyncio.run(bot.polling())

I was creating a telegram bot using pytelegrambotapi. It worked on my device with Python 3.12. But when I tried to host it on Render, I got this error. Ig, the problem is it's using older version of Python but I couldn't fix it.

Is it running in a Jupyter notebook?
